# Ruby on Rails2: is there a way to minimize css and js when in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimization

js and css files can be pretty big in order to be human readable. 
Is there some sort of gem that will minimize all the css and js upon running in production mode to decrease load times for the end user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

> http://synthesis.sbecker.net/pages/asset_packager

Alternatives:

> http://david-burger.blogspot.com/2008/02/minify-rails-javascript-and-css-with.html
>
> https://github.com/thumblemonks/smurf

Answer (score 1):

[Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) is also another asset packaging for rails.